# HashMap.get returns true instead of an element

Tags: java

So I'm trying to make a program that will count the number of times a unique word appears in a small file using HashMap. However, when I try to increase the count on a repeating word by using .get(key) on my HashMap, it returns true instead of the integer value that I want to cast to. How can I get my code to return the value instead of a boolean? Here's my code so far:

```
public class CountWords
{
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Map<String, Object> words = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<FindCommons> list = new ArrayList<>();
    
    read(words, list);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
}

public static void read (Map<String, Object> words, ArrayList<FindCommons> list) {
    try {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("file.txt"));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);

            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                line = st.nextToken();
                
                if (words.containsKey(line)) {
                    System.out.println(words.get(line)); //this returns boolean
                    //int count = (int) words.get(line));
                    words.put(line, list.add(new FindCommons(1, line)));
                }
                else {
                    words.put(line, list.add(new FindCommons(1, line)));
                    
                }
            }
        }

        input.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    }
    catch (IOException e){ 
    }
}
}
```

My FindCommons class:

import java.util.ArrayList;
public class FindCommons{

```
private String word;
private int count;

public FindCommons(int count, String word) {
    this.count = count;
    this.word = word;
}

public int getNumber() {
    return count;
}

public String getWord() {
    return word;
}

public String toString() {
    return String.format("%-20s %5d", word, count);
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you using `Map<String, Object>` instead of `Map<String, Integer>`?  Better typing would have made clear what's supposed to happen and where your problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `words.put(line, list.add(new FindCommons(1, line)));` to add the items to the HashMap. The problem is, that list.add() returns a boolean value, so it puts the Boolean into the words HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

i got same problem reason **found the reason**.

```
jobInfo.put("expireDate", jsonObjectData.get("expiryDateTime"));

jobInfo.put("applicantCount", jsonObjectData.get("appliedCount"));

jobInfo.put("userId", recruiterUserId);

list.put(userId, jobPosts.add(jobInfo));

since jobPosts.add() return boolean value.
```

so when i try **list.get(userId)** will return Boolean instead of Object.

Answer (score -1):

list.add(new FindCommons(1, line))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).